# uWSGI: --master with --emperor spawns two emperors

Tags: uwsgi

I can see that if I start uwsgi like this:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid www --gid www
```

it creates one emperor copy. But if I start it with `--master` additionally (as recommended [here](https://gist.github.com/evildmp/3094281)), it creates two emperor copies. Does it make sense to use `--master` with `--emperor`? I would say no, but if I run it without that option I get this warning:

`*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here is what [official documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Emperor.html) says:

> The emperor should generally not be run with --master, unless master
>   features like advanced logging are specifically needed.

If you're wondering what `master` option does, [here](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Glossary.html?highlight=master) is the answer:

> master
>
> uWSGI’s built-in prefork+threading multi-worker management
>   mode, activated by flicking the master switch on. For all practical
>   serving deployments it’s not really a good idea not to use master
>   mode.

So, to summarize:

- Use `--master` for usual uWSGI instance,
- Do not use `--master` for uWSGI Emperor.

Comment: So would this mean the WARNING log message is unwarranted?

Comment: I guess, yes. Maybe the uwsgi instance cannot distinguish whether it was called with emperor or not - i don't know.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree - the documentation says it is not a good idea **NOT** to use it, in production anyway; I guess the double negative could be written more clearly.

Therefore it would appear it IS a good idea to use it, hence the warning.

Comment: As I understand, production server should not run uwsgi instances standalone - I mean, without any "overseer". If you run "simlple" uwsgi instance, it's just an instance - no forks/threads, and if it crashes no one except you will launch it again.

So, you can run uwsgi --master which will create uwsgi "overseer", and the overseer will launch several "simple" uwsgi instances, with fork/threads and restart capabilities.

Comment: However, emperor already takes care of forks, threads and restarts for all its vassals, so there is no need for --master. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add some specific information for using harakiri mode for vassals running under emperor.  If master is not also in the config for the vassals harakiri will have no effect regardless of whether master/harakiri is specified in the emperor config.  Given an example emperor config:

```
[uwsgi]
emperor = ...
daemonize = ...
emperor-pidfile = ...
vassal-set = enable-metrics=1
emperor-stats = 127.0.0.1:6000
```

The vassals will need the following for harakiri to work:

```
[uwsgi]
strict
processes = 4
stats = 127.0.0.1:5000
memory-report
daemonize = ...
pidfile = ...
close-on-exec
py-tracebacker = /tmp/tbsocket
master
harakiri = 5
harakiri-verbose
```

Note that master and harakiri are both present in the vassal and setting them in emperor config would have no effect on the vassals for uwsgi version 2.0.12