# uwsgi : why two processes are loaded per each app?

Tags: python, nginx, wsgi, uwsgi

```
root@www:~# ps aux | grep uwsgi
root      4660  0.0  0.0  10620   892 pts/1    S+   19:13   0:00 grep --color=auto uwsgi
root     19372  0.0  0.6  51228  6628 ?        Ss   06:41   0:03 uwsgi --master --die-on-term --emperor /var/www/*/uwsgi.ini
root     19373  0.0  0.1  40420  1292 ?        S    06:41   0:03 uwsgi --master --die-on-term --emperor /var/www/*/uwsgi.ini
www-data 19374  0.0  1.9  82640 20236 ?        S    06:41   0:03 /usr/local/bin uwsgi --ini /var/www/app2/uwsgi.ini
www-data 19375  0.0  2.4  95676 25324 ?        S    06:41   0:03 /usr/local/bin uwsgi --ini /var/www/app3/uwsgi.ini
www-data 19385  0.0  2.1  90772 22248 ?        S    06:41   0:03 /usr/local/bin uwsgi --ini /var/www/app2/uwsgi.ini
www-data 19389  0.0  2.0  95676 21244 ?        S    06:41   0:00 /usr/local/bin uwsgi --ini /var/www/app3/uwsgi.ini
```

above is `ps` output of uwsgi processes. Strange thing is that for each ini files there are two instances loaded - even I have two uwsgi masters. is this normal?

the deployment strategy for uwsgi is

- have Emperor managed by upstart
- Emperor searches for each `uwsgi.ini` in apps folder

**uwsgi.conf** for upstart:

```
# simple uWSGI script

description "uwsgi tiny instance"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

exec uwsgi --master --die-on-term --emperor "/var/www/*/uwsgi.ini"
```

**uwsgi.ini**(I have two apps, and both apps have same ini except app# numbering):

```
[uwsgi]
# variables
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
projectname = myproject
projectdomain = www.myproject.com
base = /var/www/app2
# config
enable-threads
protocol = uwsgi
venv = %(base)/
pythonpath = %(base)/
wsgi-file = %(base)/app.wsgi
socket = /tmp/%(projectdomain).sock
logto = %(base)/logs/uwsgi.log
```

Comment: Did you resolve this only by removing `--master` flag? I still get two child processes spawned for my application, even when I have removed `--master` flag and I have only one emperor process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You started it with the --master option, which spawns a master process to control the workers.

From the official documentation https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Glossary.html?highlight=master

> **master**
>
> uWSGI’s built-in prefork+threading multi-worker management mode, activated by flicking the master switch on. For all practical serving deployments it’s not really a good idea not to use master mode.

You should read http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#master
And also this thread might have some info for you. [uWSGI: --master with --emperor spawns two emperors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055002/uwsgi-master-with-emperor-spawns-two-emperors)

It is generally not recommended to use --master and --emperor together.

Comment: thanks, I blindly followed the upstart tutorials on their doc page: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Upstart.html#using-the-emperor

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess on this topic is that it should be transfer to Server Fault indeed.
But here is the answer:

You should have started the upstart script two time ;-)

Just try to kill the main ROOT process with a SIGTERM and see if childs process died to.
If you have run the upstart script twice, you will have one ROOT and Two childs remaining.