# uWSGI Emperor configuration

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I have been struggling to deploy a flask app to my server using uWSGI in
Emperor mode all day and am at a loss why it is not working.  I have read all the other uWSGI Emperor mode questions here & asked on #uwsgi & the mailing list with no reply.

My setup is nginx (1.4.6-1ubuntu3.2), uWSGI==2.0.10 installed via pip
into a virtualenv, Flask==0.10.1, and Python 3.4.0.  supervisord is
responsible for launching the Emperor process.

The flask app itself works fine when I start it manually bound to a TCP port, and when I manually run uwsgi like:

```
uwsgi -s /tmp/oauthsvc.sock -w wsgi --stats /tmp/oauthsvc-stats.sock
```

I do notice that even though I think I configured the vassal to use a
unix socket, it reports on startup that it is listening to http://127.0.0.1:5000/

I verified with strace that nginx is opening the socket, and permissions
of that socket are 777:

```
srwxrwxrwx 1 oauthsvc oauthsvc 0 Jun  3 18:34 /tmp/oauthsvc.sock
srwxrwxrwx 1 oauthsvc oauthsvc 0 Jun  3 18:08 /tmp/oauthsvc-stats.sock
```

But the connection eventually just times out.

My configs & some log output follows.

The nginx config is as simple as can be:

```
server {                                                                    
    listen 80;                                                              
    server_name default;                                                    

    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }          
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }          

    location / {                                                            
        include uwsgi_params;                                               
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/oauthsvc.sock;                                 
    }                                                                       
}
```

supervisor launches the emporer process with this command:

```
[program:oauthsvc-emperor]                                                      
command=/services/oauthsvc/services/oauthsvc/bin/uwsgi --emperor /services/oauthsvc/etc/uwsgi/vassals --die-on-term --uid 1005 --gid 1005 --logto /services/oauthsvc/var/log/uwsgi/emperor.log
user=oauthsvc                                                                   
autostart=true                                                                  
autorestart=true                                                                
redirect_stderr=true
```

The vassal's ini file looks like:

```
[uwsgi]                                                                         
# do not turn on master mode when spawned by emperor                            
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055002/uwsgi-master-with-emperor-spawns-two-emperors
#master = true                                                                  
protocol = uwsgi                                                                
socket = /tmp/oauthsvc.sock                                                     
stats = /tmp/oauthsvc-stats.sock                                                
daemonize = /services/oauthsvc/var/log/uwsgi/oauthsvc.log                       
chdir = /services/oauthsvc/services/oauthsvc/oauthsvc-server                    
wsgi-file = wsgi.py                                                             
callable = app                                                                  
chmod-socket = 777                                                              
uid = 1005                                                                      
gid = 1005                                                                      
virtualenv = /services/oauthsvc/services/oauthsvc                               
# PYTHONHOME                                                                    
home = /services/oauthsvc/services/oauthsvc                                     
#env =                                                                           
processes = 4
vacuum = true                                                                   
# If you start uWSGI without threads, the Python GIL will not be enabled, so    
# threads generated by your application will never run unless you include:      
enable-threads = true
harakiri = 30
```

And finally, wsgi.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                          

from oauthsvc.flask.server import parse_args, configured_app                    

args = parse_args()                                                             
app = configured_app(args.config, debug=args.debug)                             
app.run()
```

The emperor log:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.10 (64bit) on [Wed Jun  3 18:34:25 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.2 on 03 June 2015 18:32:12
os: Linux-3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015
nodename: ip-10-0-1-224
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /
detected binary path: /services/oauthsvc/src/bs-oauth-svc.2015-06-03.183113/bin/uwsgi
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 30038
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
*** starting uWSGI Emperor ***
*** has_emperor mode detected (fd: 6) ***
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from oauthsvc.ini
```

The vassal log:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.10 (64bit) on [Wed Jun  3 18:34:25 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.2 on 03 June 2015 18:32:12
os: Linux-3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015
nodename: ip-10-0-1-224
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /services/oauthsvc/etc/uwsgi/vassals
detected binary path: /services/oauthsvc/src/bs-oauth-svc.2015-06-03.183113/bin/uwsgi
chdir() to /services/oauthsvc/services/oauthsvc/oauthsvc-server
your processes number limit is 30038
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
 *** WARNING: you have enabled harakiri without post buffering. Slow upload could be rejected on post-unbuffered webservers ***
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/oauthsvc.sock fd 3
Python version: 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:08:40)  [GCC 4.8.2]
Set PythonHome to /services/oauthsvc/services/oauthsvc
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x135d4d0
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 363840 bytes (355 KB) for 4 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Answer (score 1):

Brian on the uWSGI mailing list solved this for me.  The answer is: don't call app.run() in the wsgi.py file!  I knew it would be something embarrassing.