# connect() to unix:/tmp/socket.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I am following [**this tutorial**](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/nginx/deploy-django-applications-using-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) to host django application nginx but it gives

> 502 Bad Getway error connect() to unix:/tmp/socket.sock failed (111:
>   Connection refused) while connecting to upstream.

Below is my sample.ini

```
[uwsgi]
project = mysite
base = /home/ubuntu/Arti/Project

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 2

socket = /tmp/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
```

Below is my uwsgi.conf

```
description "uWSGI"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
respawn

env UWSGI=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi
env LOGTO=/var/log/uwsgi.log

exec $UWSGI --master --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites --die-on-term --uid django  --gid www-data --logto $LOGTO
```

nginx file

```
server {
    listen 8087;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/Arti/Project/mysite/;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/tmp/mysite.sock;

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check, if Django is able to start at all within your virtual env: `python manage.py runserver`. Also, there is some info regarding using `--emperor` with `--master`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15856871/2491564